# What is the best motion interpolation software out there?

Tags: video-player

I am looking for a player with a motion interpolation feature.

For example, I have a 24 fps movie and I want to watch it in 60 fps using **on-the-fly motion interpolation**. CPU solutions are preferred.

Currently I am using `SVP` but it produces too much artifacts.

Paid solutions are welcome as well.

Comment: Which OS do you want it for?

Comment: @ThomasWeller, Windows. But if there are ultimate solutions for Linux only, they are acceptable too.